# Let $\phi$ $\ne$ A, B, C, $\subseteq$ R

Tags: calculus

If:

(1) For every a $\in$ A there exists b $\in$ B such that a $\le$ b.

(2) For every b $\in$ B there exists c $\in$ C such that b $\le$ c.

(3) For every c $\in$ C there exists a $\in$ A such that c $\le$ a.

Then sup A = sup B = sup C.

It's seems obvious but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \in A$, then there is $b \in B$ such that $a \le b.$ It follows that $ a \le \sup B$ and then $\sup A \le \sup B$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Sure thank you.

What about if A, B and C are not bounded from above ?

Comment: Then $ \sup A = \sup B = \sup C = \infty.$